# Midas (Gecko Rich Text Editor) in XUL through the <editor> element cannot be enabled

Tags: javascript, xul, midas-editor

I am trying to use [Midas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Midas) through the  [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/editor) of XUL following the instructions of [this article](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2007/02/xul-clippings-midas-rich-text-editor/). So far I have the code below:

```
<window id="main" title="Anunciador Blog Editor" width="300" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <script type="application/x-javascript">
    <![CDATA[ 
    var editor = null;
    function onLoad() {
        editor = document.getElementById('editor');
        editor.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
    }

    function onBoldButtonCommand() {
        editor.contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null);
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
    ]]>
    </script>
    <button label="Bold" oncommand="onBoldButtonCommand();" />
    <editor id="editor" type="content-primary" editortype="html" src="about:blank" flex="1" />
</window>
```

However, when I click in the "Bold" button with some text selected in the `<editor>`, the text is not altered and the JS console presents the following error:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005
(NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMNSHTMLDocument.execCommand]"  nsresult: "0x80004005
(NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://anunciador/content/main.xul :: 
onBoldButtonCommand :: line 14"  data: no]
```

That does not make sense to me because I have enabled the edit mode with:

```
editor.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
```

Also, if I only change the line

```
<editor id="editor" type="content-primary" editortype="html" src="about:blank" flex="1" />
```

to

```
<xhtml:iframe id="editor" src="about:blank"></xhtml:iframe>
```

I can edit and format the text in the iframe (but I really prefer to use editor).

Did I forget something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long research, it seems that the problem is a [bug in Gecko](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671248) - a recurrent one, BTW. Apparently, it is *finally* [solved.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=434998).

While we wait for a public build (or if you cannot use the future newer version of XULRunner or Firefox), you can use the [`commandManager` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/editor#p-commandManager) of the editor as a workaround. This object provides a method called `doCommand()` which can be used for formatting text. This method has three parameters: a string representing the command (which is different from the one accepted by `execCommand()`, a param object (which is REALLY cumbersome of obtaining but can be ignored for some time) and the `contentWindow` of the editor.

If you want e.g. to make the selection bold, just use this method this way:

```
function onBoldButtonCommand() {
    editor.commandManager.doCommand("cmd_bold", {}, editor.contentWindow)
}
```

If your command needs params, however, it can become a bit more complicated. First, you will need an instance of the [`nsICommandParams` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Editor_Embedding_Guide#nsICommandParams) (which will be a C++ object wrapped by JavaScript object). Obtaining this object involves some very esoteric code, apparently involving something like XPCOM or whatnot:

```
var commandParams = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/embedcomp/command-params;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICommandParams);
```

In this object we will set the parameters of the command as key-value pairs. [There](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Editor_Embedding_Guide) we have a list of parameters accepted by all commands. Do not be afraid of the fact of this page refers to C++ code - you can map it to JavaScript intuitively. Also, hopefully it *seems* that all commands receive only one param, `"state_attribute"`. If we want to set the [color of a text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Editor_Embedding_Guide#cmd_fontColor), for example, we set the parameter this way in the param object:

```
commandParams.setCStringValue("state_attribute", "#FF0000");
```

Then you "just" call `doCommand()` using the parameter this time:

```
editor.commandManager.doCommand("cmd_fontColor", commandParams, editor.contentWindow);
```

The code below is a working example of using `doCommand()` both with and without parameters:

```
<window id="main" title="Anunciador Blog Editor" width="300" height="300"
   xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <script type="application/x-javascript">
   <![CDATA[
   var editor = null;
   function onLoad() {
       editor = document.getElementById('editor');
       editor.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
   }

   function onBoldButtonCommand() {
       editor.commandManager.doCommand("cmd_bold", {}, editor.contentWindow)
   }

    function onRedTextCommand() {
        var commandParams = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/embedcomp/command-params;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICommandParams);
        commandParams.setCStringValue("state_attribute", "#FF0000");
        editor.commandManager.doCommand("cmd_fontColor", commandParams, editor.contentWindow)
    }

   window.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
   ]]>
   </script>
   <toolbar>
       <button label="Bold" oncommand="onBoldButtonCommand();" />
       <button label="Red" oncommand="onRedTextCommand();" />
   </toolbar>
   <editor id="editor" type="content-primary" editortype="html" src="about:blank" flex="1" />
</window>
```

Also, this [page](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/editor/Editor_Embedding_Guide.html) can be helpful and [this one](http://yansanmo.progysm.com/doc/xul) yet more helpful (although partly written in French!).